# Passing variable from javascript to php with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable from js to PHP with no success. I have read all the similar questions but i had no luck. $id keeps getting the value of "52" which means my post request is not received...

```
$(document).on("click", ".info-button", function () {

    var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body .modal-text").text(myBookId);

    var variableToSend = myBookId;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "jsTophp.php",
        data:{ id : variableToSend }, 
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); 
        }
    })
});
```

And my jsTophp.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else {
    $id = 52;
}
?>
```

here is my html in movies.php file

```
include 'jsTophp.php';

<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <p class="modal-text"></p>
                <?php 
                    $movie = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id=$id");

                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($movie);

                    echo '  
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="info-image">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="'.$row['cover_path'].'" style="width:150px;height:200px;"> 
                    </div>
                    </div>   

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h4>Title: '.$row['title'].'</h4>
                        <h4>Director: '.$row['director'].'</h4>
                        <h4>Year: '.$row['d'].'</h4>
                        <h4>Description: '.$row['description'].'</h4>
                        <a href=""><img class="imdb-img" src="images/IMDb-Icon.png" style="width:80px;height:80px;"></a>
                        <a href=""><img class="imdb-img" src="images/youtube_logo.png" style="width:60px;height:40px;"></a>
                    </div>
                '; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the output if you console.log() the variableToSend before starting the AJAX request?

Comment: U can try to replace this var `variableToSend` with a number, for example. Then u can see if your ajax works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering @Dragony. variableToSend takes a value depending on what html element you click on. I am checking with alert(variableToSend); and it has the value i want...

Comment: try to see what is the response you getting in the network in developer tools in browser

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan tried it...doesn't work :(

Comment: I don't see any other obvious mistake in the code. How are you checking what variable is received by PHP?

Comment: make var_dump($_POST)

Comment: also try to print $GLOBALS to check what u r getting in the request.

Comment: Where are you checking var_dump()? In the chrome dev tools or from the brower?

Comment: Check browser's console and network tab to see if request is going..

Comment: @pritesh i've checked at network tab. it's receiving the request with the correct data...

Comment: Can you post your `html` code?

Comment: My question: what is the jsTophp page doing? If you post your ajax then manually navigate to this page of course it will have an id of 52. Even if  you are posting to the same page the php code has already run so it will be 52.

Comment: @OsamaSayed i have updated my post :) Thanks for the help again guys...

Comment: @Matt jsTophp.php checks if the post request id received, if not it sets $id to a integer so im  not getting an  mysqli_fetch_array() error :P first time im trying to pass a variable from js to php and i am really confused

Comment: @Dimitriskk Why don't I happen to see in your `html` code an element with class 'info-button'? Where is it?

Comment: @OsamaSayed  <div class="centered">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info text-center info-button" data-id='.$row['id'].' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Info</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning center">Rent</button> 
                                </div><br>

Comment: @OsamaSayed sorry for this, i can post my entire html because its over 300 lines. this is the buttons that triggers the modal

Comment: How is your `movies.php` called? Because for me it seems you call `jsTophp.php` from your ajax and then include the same in `movies.php` and expect the value `id` to be set from the ajax when you call `movies.php`? If you include `jsTophp.php` in your `movies.php` then try calling `movies.php` from your ajax instead.

Comment: `jsTophp.php` successfully receives your argument, sets `$id` correctly, but then PHP finishes, and nothing has been done with that `$id`. When you reload `movies.php` (which is unrelated with the Ajax call), `jsTophp.php` is executed again, but this time there is no posted argument, and so the `$id` variable is now 52, which is used to build your page. So far the explanation of what you experience. But what do you *expect* to happen when the user clicks the button?

Comment: Also note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is basically correct, you confirmed that your request succeeds, the issue is probably more of a misunderstanding:

Your ajax calls `jsTophp.php` with a `POST request` but this file doesn't seem to do anything with your `$id`.

You expect this `$id` to be set in your `movies.php` because you include the file in the top. Just because you might have called `jsTophp.php` before it doesn't mean that the result of the execution of this script is persisted, so that you could access it in your `movies.php`. You are just including the source code, which means the `movies.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else {
    $id = 52;
}
?>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="modal-text"></p>
...
```

What you instead want to do is, call this script in your ajax call instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "movies.php",
    data:{ id : variableToSend }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }
})
```

I know, many assumptions from my end, but your question, code and the comments lead to this conclusion. Hopefully it's the problem and it will help you.

Comment: i tried it before...doesnt work either...im getting really frustrated :(

Comment: Try $(this).attr('data-id');

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my code, which does the same thing that you want, and it's working as expected.

HTML

```
<a onclick="addToCart(this, 1)" href="#!">Click me</a><br>
```

JS

```
function addToCart(elem, pid){
var pid = pid;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "cart_add_product_ajax.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
            pid:     pid
          },
    success: function(res) {
        if(res == 1){
            location.reload();
        }else{
            //
        }
    }
});
}
```

PHP

```
    if($_POST){
        $pid     = $_POST['pid'];

        if(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id=".$pid)) {
            echo 1; //success
        }else{
            echo 0; //failure
        }
    }
```

Also to check what is happening in the PHP code (e.x. If there any errors) use chrome inspector > network (tab). Click on the response that you got from the server. For example you could type in PHP

```
var_dump($_POST['id'])
```

And view what it returns in the inspector.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Whatever you echoes in php, it will be the value returned in the success function of  $.ajax